# How to work with Roles (asp.net) without hardcoding them? 

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, roles

When Roles are created/deleted I wouldn't want to modify the code.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Super Admin") ||
    HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") ||
    HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Support"))
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        ListBox1.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles().Except(
            new[] { "Super Admin" });

    }
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Support"))
    {
        ListBox1.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles().Except(
            new[] { "Super Admin", "Admin" });
    }
    fillDropDownCustomers();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roles work by assigning a value to something a user can do. The Roles dont change but the behaviour for those roles does. Ultra dynamic solutions tend to be overkill.

So perhaps you have the following roles

- Super Admin
- Support
- Admin

You can have different Actions (This would depend on your system)

- View
- Edit
- Approve

Etc

- Super Admin [View, Edit, Approve]
- Support [View]
- Admin [View, Edit]

The dynamic part comes in the assignment of Actions. Doing things this way you dont care what Role someone is in but what actions they have. The Actions are the dynamic aspect in this relationship. When a request is made you will use the users Role to fetch the assigned Actions to that role (Database Driven to make modifiable)

Incorporating this into your Database structure as "***Role has many Actions***", means that if things change in the future you will need to update the relationship in the database but not code.

A database structure could look something like this, depends on your needs.

- UserRole [ID, UserName, RoleID] (If user is assigned more than one role they inherit all actions, which might be duplicated and therefore selected DISTINCT or prevent this scenario, but I believe the former provides greater flexibility without complexity and limitation. NOTE: the UserRole table could be further denormalized to make UserNames unique.)
- Role [ID, Name]
- Action [ID, Name]
- RoleAction [ID, RoleID, ActionID] (Unique Key Constraint on RoleID and ActionID)

When a request is made, you identify the user etc ***UserName***, Then workout which ***Role(s)*** they are in by quering the RoleAction and thereby load their associated ***Actions***

I would use ***enums*** for your Action and Role values. This makes it easier to work with. To ensure that the Database and Code are in sink, ensure that you write a Unit Test reconcile the database values against the enum values.

Comment: I think without the use of constants as the other answers have suggested, then this would still require hard coding the roles into the code.

Comment: It would yes, but the use of roles as illustrated in the question is not well understood and therefore the desire to extend roles into something dynamic, when its actually their behavior that is dynamic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It is really helpful since I was enabling/disabling users in every single part where I needed to do an action instead of asking to the database if they were able or not. However, I still wonder what happens if a particular user is able to create certain records but not all of them: creating an action called "create" wouldn't be the most efficient solution right? Will I have to create relationships between the table Actions and the rest of the tables? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Think carefully about the solution. It could be that certain users can create only for certain conditions. This could mean actions within actions. However for the purposes of simplicity try using an identifier etc UserName which Maps to a Role which maps to a set of Behaviours. You will need to create relationships in your database (My Preference) or XML ... dont take short cuts, they always cut up to you ;) Let me know if you want details of how to implement. You use the Username to identify the role(s) and then identify the behaviours.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. What about having a N to N relationship between Roles and Actions in the DB and make relationships between that new table and the other entities in the DB. Thus, we could have in that new table the role (admin, support), the action (create, edit, delete) and a FK to each other table like Users, Contacts or whatever you have in the DB. What do you think about that? Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Obviously, the Role and the Action in the new table will also be FKs to their tables. Just in case I wasn't clear enough

Comment: Ive expanded my answer to include db structure, similar to what you have described. You are on the righ track!

Comment: Thank you so very much for providing this answer!!  This really clarified a usable approach for my client's set up. Their site uses .NET membership for setting permissions but the user base authenticates from an unmanaged 3rd party web service with no concept of roles other than to do some calculations on a couple of user properties on a tier system that changes a lot! It'll mean performing a lot of complicated logic at run time, but this is as close as I have come to finding a work around. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: @divamatrix glad its helpful to you!

Answer (score 4):

Put those values in static class:

```
public static class MyRoles
{
    public const string Admin = "Admin";
    public const string SuperAdmin = "Super Admin";
    public const string Support = "Support";
}
```

Now you can reuse them like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(MyRoles.SuperAdmin) ||
    HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(MyRoles.Admin) ||
    HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(MyRoles.Support))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is use constants. The more context answer is use IoC to push the logic into another class where you can manage the relationships form config or database.

Answer (score 0):

Either as the other answers have suggested, as Constant variables. However you would still need to change the code and republish if you were to change the name of one of the roles.

Another option would be to add the names of the roles into a config file. You would make use of the Application Settings, or a custom config class which inherits from `ConfigurationSection`. Take a look here for how http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

This way you can change the names of the roles within the web.config file and you would not have to update any code or republish the project.